# Custom Environment in Grails for Hudson/Jenkins

Tags: grails, hudson, hudson-plugins, jenkins

I'm using the Grails plugin for Jenkins (formerly Hudson) and didn't find a way to specify a custom environment for a target.

I tried `-Dgrails.env=myEnvironment war`in the `targets` input and `-Dgrails.env=integration` in the `Properties` input of the config section without any luck.

Comment: You should just be able to put `grails.env=integration` in the properties pane of the `Build With Grails` build step.  Is that what you tried?

Comment: Thanks, that works! I could have sweared I tried that out. I'll accept your answer if you post one.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should just be able to put `grails.env=integration` in the properties pane of the Build With Grails build step.  Is that what you tried?